# Java Object creation through loop

Tags: java, object, new-operator, allocation

So I create objects MyFrame, and stores them in a MyFrame array. The problem is when the loop is done, all the objects in the array are equal to the last object created.
Here's the code:

```
MyFrame [] response = new MyFrame[8];    
for(int i = 0; i<numberSplit; i++){
   response[i] = new MyFrame("","", infoS[i],"");
}
```

Here the full class if you run the main you will see that's in splitInfo and if I manually print each element in the array upon creation it works  :

```
            import java.io.*;
            import java.util.*;

            public class MyFrame {
              // Variable qui donne une valeur fixe aux fanions.
              private static BitSet [] frame = new BitSet [6];
              private static BitSet flag_1 = new BitSet(8);
              private static BitSet address = new BitSet(8);
              private static BitSet control = new BitSet(8);
              private static BitSet fcs = new BitSet(16);
              private static String info = null;

              // Constructeur pour créer des trames
              public MyFrame (BitSet address, BitSet control, String info, BitSet fcs){
                this.frame = frame;
                flag_1.set(1,7);
                this.frame[0] = flag_1;
                this.frame[1] = address;
                this.frame[2] = control;
                this.frame[3] = stringToBitSet(info);
                this.frame[4] = fcs;
                this.frame[5] = flag_1;
              }

              public MyFrame (String address, String control, String info, String fcs){
                this.frame = frame;
                flag_1.set(1,7);
                this.frame[0] = flag_1;
                this.frame[1] = stringToBitSet(address);
                this.frame[2] = stringToBitSet(control);
                this.frame[3] = stringToBitSet(info);
                this.frame[4] = stringToBitSet(fcs);
                this.frame[5] = flag_1;
              }

              // Constructeur qui prend comme entree une trame en String et la longueur du champ
              // d'information
              public MyFrame (String frameS, int infoL){
                int endIL = 24+infoL;
                this.frame = frame;
                this.frame[0] = stringToBitSet(frameS.substring(0,7));
                this.frame[1] = stringToBitSet(frameS.substring(8,16));
                this.frame[2] = stringToBitSet(frameS.substring(16,24));
                this.frame[3] = stringToBitSet(frameS.substring(24,endIL));
                this.frame[4] = stringToBitSet(frameS.substring(endIL,endIL+16));
                this.frame[5] = stringToBitSet(frameS.substring(endIL+16,endIL+24));
              }
              // Constructeur-copieur
              public MyFrame (MyFrame frm){
                  this.frame[0] = (BitSet)frm.frame[0].clone();
                this.frame[1] = (BitSet)frm.frame[1].clone();
                this.frame[2] = (BitSet)frm.frame[2].clone();
                this.frame[3] = (BitSet)frm.frame[3].clone();
                this.frame[4] = (BitSet)frm.frame[4].clone();
                this.frame[5] = (BitSet)frm.frame[5].clone();

              }
              // GETTERS

              public BitSet getAddress(){
                return this.frame[1];
              }

              public BitSet getCtrl(){
                return this.frame[2];
              }

              public BitSet getInfo(){
                return this.frame[3];
              }
                public BitSet getFCS(){
                return this.frame[4];
              }
                  public BitSet getFlag(){
                return this.frame[5];
              }

              public void setAddress(String add){

                this.frame[1] =stringToBitSet(add); 
              }

              // Convertit un BitSet en String.
              public static String bitSetToString(BitSet bs, int length){
                String result ="";
                String tempString="";
                for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
                  boolean temp = bs.get(i);
                  if (temp){
                    tempString = "1";
                  }else{
                    tempString = "0";
                  }
                  result = result.concat(tempString);
                } 
                return result;
              }

              //Convertit un String en BitSet.
              public static BitSet stringToBitSet(String bits){
                int length = bits.length();
                BitSet result = new BitSet (length);
                for(int i=0; i < length; i++){
                  if (bits.charAt(i) == '1'){
                    result.set(i);
                  }
                }
                return result;
              }
              // puisqu'on utilise le PrintWriter on prend la trame et on la transpose en une grande String
              // prend la longueur du champ info en parametre puisqu'il est variable
              public String toString(int infoL){
                String result = "";
                result = result.concat(bitSetToString(this.frame[0],8));
                result = result.concat(bitSetToString(this.frame[1],8));
                result = result.concat(bitSetToString(this.frame[2],8));
                result = result.concat(bitSetToString(this.frame[3],infoL));
                result = result.concat(bitSetToString(this.frame[4],16));
                result = result.concat(bitSetToString(this.frame[5],8));
                return result;
              }

              // print
              public static void print (MyFrame trame, int infoL) {
                System.out.println("Fanion : "+bitSetToString(trame.frame[0],8));
                System.out.println("Addresse : " +bitSetToString(trame.frame[1],8));
                System.out.println("Control : "+bitSetToString(trame.frame[2],8));
                System.out.println("Info : "+bitSetToString(trame.frame[3],infoL));
                System.out.println("FCS : "+bitSetToString(trame.frame[4],16));
                System.out.println("Fanion : "+bitSetToString(trame.frame[5],8));
              }
              // Methode qui prend une trame en parametre et retourne une trame reponse
              public MyFrame [] processFrame(){
                MyFrame [] response = new MyFrame [8];
                BitSet control = this.getCtrl();
                String ctrlS = MyFrame.bitSetToString(control,8);
                BufferedReader userIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;
                String address, info;

                // Determine quel type de trame la trame est
                if(!control.get(0)){
                  System.out.println("Cette trame est de type I");
                }else if (control.get(0) && !control.get(1)){
                  System.out.println("Cette trame est de type S");

                  // RR
                  if (ctrlS.substring(0,4).equals("1000")){
                    System.out.println("RR");

                    // Desire envoyer des trames
                    System.out.println("Desirez-vous envoyer une ou des trame(s)?");
                    for(;;){
                      try{
                        if( userIn.readLine().equals("oui")){
                          System.out.println("Les addresses sont en format binaire et commence toujours par 1");
                          System.out.println("Par exemple : Station Primaire = 10101010");
                          System.out.println("Station Secondaire 00 = 10000000");
                          System.out.println("Station Secondaire 01 = 10000001");
                          System.out.println("Station Secondaire 10 = 10000010");
                          System.out.println("...");
                          System.out.println("Station Secondaire 11111111 = 11111111");
                          System.out.println("\n");
                          System.out.println("Entrer l'addresse pour quel station ces trames sont destinées : ");
                          address = userIn.readLine();

                          System.out.println("Veuillez entrer l'information en binaire que vous-voulez envoyer à l'addresse "+ address +" : ");
                          info = userIn.readLine();

                          response = splitInfo(info);

                          print(response[0],512);

                          // ajoute l'addresse au trames 
                          for(int i = 0; i < response.length-1; i++){
                            response [i].setAddress(address);
                          }

                          // retourne la serie de trames
                          return response;

                          // N'a aucune trame a envoyer
                        }else if (userIn.readLine().equals("non")){
                          response [0] = new MyFrame ("10101010", "10000000","","0000000000000000");
                          return response;

                        }else{
                          System.out.println("Veuillez entrer soit 'oui' soit 'non'");
                        }

                        break;
                      }catch(IOException e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                      }
                    }


                  }
                  // RNR
                  else if(ctrlS.substring(0,1).equals("1001")){
                  }
                  // FRAME ERROR
                  else{}


                }else if (control.get(0) && control.get(1)){
                  System.out.println("Cette trame est de type U : ");
                  // SRNM
                  if (ctrlS.equals("11001001")){
                    System.out.print("SRNM \n");
                    response [0] = new MyFrame("10101010","11001110","","0000000000000000");
                    return response;
                  }
                  // DISC
                  else if(ctrlS.equals("11001010")){
                  }
                  // UA
                  else if(ctrlS.equals("11001110")){        
                    System.out.print("UA \n");
                  }
                  // FRMR : Report receipt of an unacceptable frame
                  else{

                  }

                }

                return null;
              }


              // Methode qui prend un string d'information a envoyer et le subdivise en 
              // string binaire de 512 bits et cree le nombre de trame en consequence
              // par defaut la limite en terme de longeur totale est de 8 (4096 bits)
              public static MyFrame [] splitInfo (String info){
                Integer binVal = new Integer(256);
                String infoBin = "";
                String [] infoS = new String [8];
                MyFrame [] response = new MyFrame [8]; 
                int numberSplit = 0;

                // Transcode les caractere en UTF-8 binaire
                try{
                  byte [] string = info.getBytes("UTF-8");
                  for(int i = 0 ; i<= string.length-1; i++){
                    infoBin = infoBin.concat(binVal.toBinaryString(string[i]));
                  }

                  // Si le message resultant est plus que 64 octets (512 bits)
                  // le splitter en message de 512 bits
                  if (infoBin.length() >511){

                    for (int i = 0; i<=((int)(infoBin.length()/512)); i++){
                      if(((i+1)*512) > infoBin.length()){
                        infoS[i] = infoBin.substring(512*i, infoBin.length());
                      }else{
                        infoS[i] = infoBin.substring(512*i, 512*(i+1));
                      }
                      numberSplit++;

                    }

                    // Creer les trames
                    for (int i = 0; i<numberSplit; i++){
                                MyFrame temp = new MyFrame ("","",infoS[i],"0000000000000000");
                      response[i] = new MyFrame(temp);
                     //print(temp,512);

              }

             print(response[0],512);
              print(response[1],512);
                    //System.out.println(response[0]);
                    //System.out.println(response[1]);

                   //print(response2[0],512);
                    return response;

                  }else{
                    response [0] = new MyFrame("","",infoBin,"0000000000000000");
                    return response;
                  }
                }catch(Exception e){}
                return null;
              }


              public static void main(String args[]){

                MyFrame trame = new MyFrame("0000000"+1,"10001000","","0000000000000011");
                print(trame,0);
                MyFrame trame2 = new MyFrame(trame.toString(0), 0);
                print(trame2,0);
                BitSet compare = new BitSet(8);
                compare.set(0,2,true);
                compare.set(4);
                compare.set(7,true);
                System.out.println("compare : " + compare.toString() + " ctrl : " + trame2.frame[2]);
                System.out.println(trame2.frame[2].equals(compare));
                trame2.setAddress("10111001");
                MyFrame [] x = splitInfo("HEAKdsANSDLASDIASDLMASLDMASKDHAKSNDKAasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasSMDKASNDKNASKDNASODDFKANSKBFNSKANSDADKABSFKBNASKDNAKSDNOKGJIKASNDIKNASDNA");





              }
            }
```

Comment: How do you know they're all the same?  Please show a complete test-case (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: *"The problem is when the loop is done, all the objects in the array are equal to the last object created."* No, they aren't. What makes you think they are?

Comment: Please post code for infoS declaration and MyFrame definition, and explain what you mean by "equal to last object created".

Comment: @Adam if i use the print method, it prints the same value for each info field of the MyFrame object which is infoS[numberSplit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to test if the objects are really different objects is `System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(object))`

but the code you posted, as said before, is creating and saving distinct objects.

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet above, that's not possible. Each of them is a seperate new object.

Couple of things

- If MyFrame is a custom class, did you override equals/hashcode poorly?
- Are you seeing the same info across MyFrame instances? Could it be a poorly declared static variable?